# Always writable vs. always readable

Tags: database, cassandra, amazon-dynamodb

I am reading the book "Cassandra --- The Definitive Guide".  In one page, the book says

> Dynamo Cassandra choose to be always writable, opting to defer the complexity of reconciliation  to read operations, and realize tremendous performance gains.

But I don't fully understand why always readable is more expensive than always writable, can anyone give me the intuition or some examples?  For example, if a database chooses 'always read', then what kind of performance loss it might get?

Answer (score 4):

@Keelar

Write operations in Cassandra just involves appending data (with timestamp) to a file (to simplify). Therefore writing is tremendously fast. The burden of data reconciliation is brought to read time.

When reading some data, Cassandra will read values from many nodes and does a merge-sort to take the *latest* version of written data, using the write timestamp as mean of comparison. Consequently, since you need to do a little bit work, read is said to be slighly less performant than write.

That being said, the folks at Datastax have done much work and now read performance is roughtly equivalent to write perf.

This explanation is very simplified. For more details, you can read the official documentation which explains the write path/read path **[here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/dml/manage_dml_intro_c.html#concept_ds_g2s_y1w_zj)** and **[here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/dml/dml_about_reads_c.html#concept_ds_vrp_4qx_zj)**

Comment: +1 for good explanation for "Cassandra choose to be always writable, opting to defer the complexity of reconciliation to read operations", but I am asking something like what if a database chooses 'always read', then what kind of performance loss it might get?

Comment: If you choose to maximize read  throughput then you somehow trade-off consistency. A system that always replies values very fast on read requests cannot guarantee consistent values and be partition tolerant. That's the A (Availability) of the CAP theorem.